# redirect output files in different directory

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and trying to put output files in a different directory.piece of code is as below

```
use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
use File::Path; 

    foreach my $file (sort({uc($a) cmp uc($b)} keys(%$ch_ref))) {
        my $num = keys(%{$$ch_ref{$file}});
             print "\n     -> $string $file ($num):\n";
        foreach my $sid (keys(%{$$ch_ref{$file}})) {
            if ($type == $PRINT_OLD) {
                open ( my $output, '>>',$file );
                        print {$output} "  something";
                close ( $output ) or die $!;
            }
```

Comment: You need to prepend the filename with an absolute path.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post and fix the formatting/indentation?

Comment: You're repeating the same code 6 times. Why not just `open` and `close` the file once?

Comment: 1. Can you please explain with an example to prepend the filename with an absolute path as per above code.

Comment: `'/full/path/to/' . $file`

Answer (score 2):

The third argument to `open()` is the full path to the file that you want to open. Currently, you're just giving it the filename. but you can expand that to include the directory as well.

Something like this:

```
my $dir = '/path/to/some/directory';

open my $output, '>>', $dir . $string . '_' . $file;
```

You should really be checking the success of the `open()` call, and it's a bit easier to give a sensible error message if you build the filename into a variable first.

```
my $dir = '/path/to/some/directory';
my $filename = "$dir${string}_$file";

open my $output, '>>', $filename
  or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
```

Note that using `${string}` instead of `$string` means that you can use it directly in the string without the name getting tangled up with the following `_` character.

I'd also strongly recommend dropping your use of prototypes on your subroutine. Perl prototypes are often far more trouble than they are worth.

Also, there's no need to `open()` and `close()` your file so many times. Just open it at the top of the loop (it will be automatically closed at the end as `$output` goes out of scope).